# Magento 2 phtml file not called in email template file

Tags: magento-2.1, email-templates, phtml

I am trying to call phtml file in my email template using following code but it's generate error

**Error Log :**

```
[2017-02-13 08:45:18] main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'Company_Module::abc.phtml' in module: '' block's name: 'magento\framework\view\element\template_0' [] []
```

**Code I used in email template file**

```
{{block class='Magento\\Framework\\View\\Element\\Template' area='frontend' template='Company_Module::abc.phtml'}}
```

**Phtml template file path**

```
app/code/Company/Module/view/frontend/template/abc.phtml
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your file path is as below

**app/code/Company/Module/view/frontend/templates/abc.phtml**

You have created template folder instead of templates

Magento 2 have foldername templates